# Import file without knowing it the name

Tags: python, pandas

In the same folder i have a script (in python) that needs to import a document for which i only now that it has .csv extension(the name of the file is different every time). How can i do that ?

I've tried using: `data = pd.read_csv(r'./*.csv')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use glob: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're guaranteed the CSV file exists, use the [`iglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) method:

```
from glob import iglob
df = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv')))
```

The `glob` module is useful for wildcard matching. `iglob` in particular will return an iterator; all you need to do is just extract the first value it yields and pass that to `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing more with your files and need their paths, I would suggest using [path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) from the pathlib module.

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


csv_files = Path.cwd().glob('*.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(next(csv_files))
```

`csv_files` is a generator of the full paths of the .csv files. This is similar to `iglob`, but that returns only the file names.